# Sylow 2-subgroup of Suzuki Group $Sz(8)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, sylow-theory

Is there a computational way to find the isomorphism class containing the Sylow $p$-subgroup of a large group?

For example, the Sylow $2$-subgroup of the Suzuki group $Sz(8)$.

Comment: Probably you will get downvote because we expect you to write your attemption in this website so you should write what did you do

Comment: I have tried to google different things and look at a lot of character theory groups.

Comment: You may want to give GAP (https://www.gap-system.org/) a try. There, you can set e.g. `s := SylowSubgroup(Sz(8),2);` and then do all kinds of analysis on your `s`.

Comment: Higman wrote a paper called 'Suzuki 2-groups' on such groups. It gives generators and relations.

Comment: I don't find this question clear. What exactly do you mean by "find a Sylow 2-subgroup"?

Comment: I edited the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sylow $2$-subgroup of $Sz(8)$ are isomorphic to $C_2^3 \cdot_{84} C_2^3$ which is SmallGroup(64,82) in the GAP library. I found this here:

[https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/61/C2%5E3.84C2%5E3.html](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/61/C2%5E3.84C2%5E3.html)

Comment: Describe how you found that in an answer. Not just the result.

Comment: It's a straightforward computer calculation. In Magma, for example: $\mathtt{G:=Sz(8);\ P:=Sylow(G,2);\ IdentifyGroup(P);\ <64, 82>}$.

Comment: I was not aware of the IdentifyGroup() command. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In GAP it is $\mathtt{IdGroup}$.